# How to log starting of Eclipse plug-ins / OSGi bundles?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle

In an Eclipse RCP application, how can I automatically log each plug-in as it is being started?

I know about these, but am looking for something more akin to Java's `-verbose:class`:

- OSGi console's ability to query the current set of plug-ins.
- Handcoding a logging call in each plug-in's activator.

This feels like an option that should already exist. Seems like there should be an option to automatically log bundle-state changes for plug-ins. But I haven't found anything after a quick search online and in books. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bundle state changes are already logged by OSGi to the Log Service. Please refer to chapter 101 of the OSGi Compendium specification.

If you want to log bundle start events using some specific mechanism other than the standard Log Service, then you can write a `BundleListener`. The trick is to get your listener registered early enough so you catch all the other bundles being started (obviously if the bundle containing the listener is started last then it will not be able to see these events).

If you are in control of the top-level application then you should be able to register the listener from the OSGi launcher, i.e. using the `BundleContext` of the system bundle itself. But the launcher is usually in control of starting bundles anyway, meaning that the time to log the start of a bundle is when your code calls `start()` on each of them! It all depends on how your application is structured.

Comment: Excellent! I'm not seeing them with the default settings. At what level are the bundle-state changes logged by OSGi to the Log Service?

Comment: According to section 101.6.1, bundle events are mapped to `LOG_INFO` level.

Comment: Thanks for your authoritative answer. In the context of Eclipse, I still haven't got the changes to be written to the log file. And a breakpoint set in `FrameworkLogEntry`'s bottommost constructor never got called unless I manufactured an error. I've tried setting `-Declipse.log.level=INFO`. Is there another option I should be setting for Eclipse or OSGi?

Comment: Do you have a Log Service implementation installed and active?

Comment: I think so. The method `LogServiceManager.bundleChanged(BundleEvent)` is called repeatedly, but `isLoggable()` keeps returning false, indirectly because `EquinoxLogWriter.isLoggable()` returns on `loggableLevel == LogService.LOG_ERROR`. There's this helpful comment: *// for now only log errors; probably need this to be configurable*. To solve this question completely, I'm guessing I need to add my own LogWriter/LogFilter to ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you answered my question. If there is a log service implementation installed, you will see it as an ACTIVE bundle when you list bundles. You don't need to debug to find this out.

Comment: Sorry. I see the bundle org.eclipse.osgi is ACTIVE. It contains an implementation of the `LogService` interface. In code, I can get the LogService via a ServiceTracker, interact with it, and debug through its steps.

Comment: It looks like Equinox sets up its own log service by default ... `EquinoxContainer` creates an `EquinoxLogServices`, which creates that `EquinoxLogWriter` I mentioned above.

Comment: Okay so there's a built-in log service implementation that throws away log entries below ERROR. Not very useful. Perhaps you need to add a bundle that implements the service properly, such as [org.eclipse.equinox.log](http://eclipse.org/equinox/bundles/) or [org.apache.felix.log](http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi).

Comment: Okay. Looks like all of these implementations require the addition of a `LogListener` to write the log entry anywhere. If I want to log at startup time as many bundle starts as possible, do I need to create a bundle with a low start level that adds the LogListener?